# What is the correct path to use for a background image in a css file in a Rails application that takes advantage of the asset pipeline?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

It seems like there should be a canonical correct answer to this question, but I can't find it in the Rails documentation or anywhere else.

What is the correct path to use for a background image in a css file in a Rails application that takes advantage of the asset pipeline?

The path, first of all, needs to work in development and in production.
If the path can't be the same in both, the difference should be apparent.

I realize the answer to this question may be different if you are using css, scss, or sass. It would be nice to know the difference between the different syntaxes. Should I use 'asset-url' or 'image-url'? Is it even possible to use plain css with the asset pipeline?

I have tried prefacing my path to the background image with '/assets/', '/images/', or just nothing preceding the image url. Nothing has worked. What will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both PATHS are correct to use in css.

With reference to rails 3.2.13.
`Sass-Rails` internally uses `asset-url's` logic same as `asset_path`(rails helper method). And `image-url` calls rails `image_path` helper method which again calls `asset_path` of rails helper method. So both methods are just calling `asset_path` of rails helper and you can use either one. So there is only syntax difference.

P.S.- Any feedback or input is most welcome.

Comment: But what IS the path? I've tried:
 background-image: image-url("/assets/images/the-image-i-want.jpg");
but that doesn't work.

Comment: Hey just use:

background-image: image-url('the-image-you-want.jpg'), and rails will automatically search your image in the images folder of the assets paths.

Comment: The answer I was looking for is in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use asset-url for sass file.
for plain css use url

Comment: I'm aware (as I hoped I indicated in my question) that helpers like 'asset-url' and 'image-url' are only available in sass or scss (compiled stylesheets). My question, though, is what is the correct path to use? I can see that it might be different, depending on the kind of compiled or non-compiled css you are using.